# pushing to docker authentication error after heroku build

Tags: docker, heroku

I am trying to push to docker but i keep coming up against a unauthorized: authentication required error.
I have tried both heroku login and heroku container:login but no joy. the error keeps coming up the i try to push to docker. the registration part worked fine.

these are my steps:

- heroku login  (works)
- heroku container:login (works)
- heroku create (works)
- cd to my folder #the directory where manage.py file exists (works)
- copied the Dockerfile here  (works)
- docker build -t registry.heroku.com/<app_name>/web . (works)
- docker push registry.heroku.com/<app_name>/web (gets stuck here :( )
- heroku container:release web -a <app_name>

Comment: Which app_name do you set in the step that fails?

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely caused by the fact that the application name in the push command does not match the Heroku app name.

When creating a new application using `heroku create` Heroku will generate a random name for you

```
$ heroku create
Creating app... done, ⬢ dry-woodland-89919
https://dry-woodland-89919.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/dry-woodland-89919.git
```

It is better to define the name during the creation (ie dsdsds23)

```
$ heroku create dsdsds23
Creating ⬢ dsdsds23... done
https://dsdsds23.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/dsdsds23.git
```

You must then use the application name when pushing to Heroku

```
docker push registry.heroku.com/dsdsds23/web
```